# Android Keystore, secure value of key

Tags: android, security, encryption, keystore

I'm currenlty investigating using the secured/improved Keystore introduced in Android 4.3.

I would like to store an encryption key inside this keystore, this key is used to encrypt a sqllite db and the values contained in my shared preferences.

When I take a look at the KeyStore Sample in the SDK I see the following:

```
public static final String ALIAS = "my_key"
```

If someone would be able to decompile my code they would be able to see the cleartext alias (= the key to retrieve the encryption key from the keystore) and hence they would be able to get a reference to my encryption key. How can I securly manage my ALIAS? or am I missing the point here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias is not sensitive information. Each keystore is associated with a password and each key has its own (optional) password too. Those are the values that must be kept safe.

Without the password(s), an attacker cannot read your key material despite knowing the alias.

Comment: Would it be possible to point out which are the passwords? I'm currently looking at KeyStoreHelper.java from the samples. I can see there is a KeyPair object which is generated from KeyPairGenerator. Will this object contain the private and public key? Will it be possible for an attacker to repackage my code and get acces to these keys?

Comment: @user2987274 The passwords are used in conjunction with the [`KeyStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) class in the `load`, `getKey` and `setKeyEntry` methods. A key does not have an associated password until you store it in a keystore. So a freshly generated `KeyPair` object has no password until you persist it in a keystore.

Comment: Just to be sure. Someone that would decompile my code and get a reference to ALIAS will not be able to repackage the code and get a reference to the KeyPair hence it wasn't persisted? or something else prevents that person to get a reference to the correct KeyPair?

Comment: @user2987274 If you don't persist your key pair, it won't exist once your application stops running. If you persist it, you choose a password and that will protect the key.

Answer (score 9):

*The below answer is for 4.3+. There were big changes to KeyStore & KeyChain classes on this release. See [here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/credential-storage-enhancements-android-43.html) for more info*

`Keystore` access is restricted by UID - your app is allocated a UID on install.

**This is what prevents other apps / processes accessing your key pair / private key**. The keystore deamon will enforce this.

This can optinally require a device pin for additional encryption. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder.html#setEncryptionRequired()

The whole point of using the software / hardware keystore is to get around the situation you describe - which is any hardcoded data in your app can be read on decompilation so it would not be secure.

@Duncans answer makes it seem that you need to keep a password around. I would advise you generate a key pair using the keystore and then use this to encrypt an AES key you can use to encrypt anything you want (much faster than using an RSA key)

You can use your hardware / sortware keystore backed private key like `keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);` and not pass any kind of password.

See [SecretKeyWrapper.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Vault/src/com/example/android/vault/SecretKeyWrapper.java) for a good example of this

Comment: so what is the solution for Android versions below 4.3 like ICS?

Comment: Well the question is about the KeyStore introduced in 4.3 so there is not really a direct parallel for < 4.3! If you want to use secret keys before this then you would prob need to include user input and some PBKDF. That said, < 4.3 is around ~25% atm so if you have a requirement to have hardware backed keys just support 4.3+